# Border Radius is unexpectedly uneven

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, icons

I have a view with an icon (from react-native-vector-icons) inside as following:

```
  return (
    <View style={styles.iconContainerStyle}>
      <Icon name='menu' size={23} style={styles.iconStyle} />
    </View>
  );
```

The following is the styling for both the components:

```
const styles = {
  iconContainerStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 30,
    width: 35,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    padding: 2
  },
  iconStyle: {
    color: '#2279b4',
  }
};
```

The weird part is that the border radius prop of 5 should give evenly rounded borders, but this is what I get:
Notice that on the right hand side, the borders are sharper then the left part!

[image]

I even tried with different borderRaduis values, its still the same concept.

Comment: Can you try with a smaller width ? I feel like your button is too wide and the right part is hidden behind something else

Comment: I tried with a width of 30 and 20 but still the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

The header you see is provided by react-native-router-flex for my scenes, I think this is also a factor as their styles are also applied on the hamburger button.

A work around (temporarily) is by supplying another parent view with he following style:

```
  <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: 35, width: 40, }}>
```

The height and width need to be a value bigger then that of the iconContainer.

Answer (score -2):

Please add `border: 1px solid #f00;` to your code to see if toggle icon is not hidden behind something.

If it looks fine, try to add seperate radius to each angle, Like:

```
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
```

and so on. Also, try to use `border-radius` styles with `!important`.